# How do i push a new key value pair to an array php?

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I know there is a lot of documentation around this but this one line of code took me ages to find in a 4000 line file, and I would like to get it right the first try.

```
file_put_contents($myFile,serialize(array($email_number,$email_address))) or die("can't open file");
    if ($address != "email@domain.com") {
        $email['headers'] = array('CC' => 'email@domain.com');
    }
}
```

After this if statement I basically want to add on

`'BCC' => 'another_email@domain.com'`

into the `$email['headers']` array (so it adds it whether the if evaluates to true or not)

Comment: See this.. create array object and assign values in the array..                                                    http://hiox.org/33288-create-array-copy-using-php.php

Comment: The line inside the if statement may not be the 'best' way (I really don't know) but it will work. $email['headers'] = array('BCC' => 'another_email@domain.com');

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can add them individually like this:

```
$array["key"] = "value";
```

Collectively, like this:

```
$array = array(
    "key"  => "value",
    "key2" => "value2"
);
```

Or you could merge two or more arrays with `array_merge`:

```
$array = array( "Foo" => "Bar", "Fiz" => "Buz" );

$new = array_merge( $array, array( "Stack" => "Overflow" ) );

print_r( $new );
```

Which results in the news key/value pairs being added in with the old:

```
Array
(
  [Foo] => Bar
  [Fiz] => Buz
  [Stack] => Overflow
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this: `$email['headers']['BCC'] = "Test@rest.com"`
but you need to add it after the if.

Answer (score 0):

```
$email['headers'] = array();

if ($address != "email@domain.com") {
   $email['headers']['CC'] = 'email@domain.com';
}

$email['headers']['BCC'] = 'another_email@domain.com';
```